# How to speed up inserting variations in WooCommerce REST API?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wp-api

Does anybody know how to speed up inserting product variations using WooCommerce REST API v3?

My script is inserting 10 new variations in single PUT request and it takes around 1 minute to complete it...

I have to insert few thousand variations every day which takes a way too long (few hours).

Or maybe API is not the right way to do that and I should use some alternative?